# preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax slice" does not bring SVG to bottom of Viewbox

Tags: svg, vue.js

Trying to make a bargraph that has dynamically changing svg's as bars using Vue, but preserveAspectRatio isn't setting them to the bottom of css Grid column I've assigned them. Just shows the padding left over for the rest of the column. Is there a conflict with dynamic variables that overrides svg Viewbox values? I'm I just dumb?

```
      <div class="openedBar">
        <svg width="36px" height="200px" viewbox="0 0 36 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax slice">
          <rect v-bind:height="svgHeights.openedBar * 2 + 'px'" width="36px"></rect>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="linkClicksBar">
        <svg width="36px" height="200px" viewbox="0 0 36 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax slice">
          <rect v-bind:height="svgHeights.linksBar * 2 + 'px'" width="36px"></rect>
        </svg>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple *issues* with your original code.

### `viewBox` is misspelled

while case sensitivity doesn't matter for html, it matters for the svg spec. This is even a trap for the creators of Vue, as Vue does this wrong when using html templates (you probably don't use them, but it caught me off guard trying to reproduce it)

It should be spelled `viewBox` (note the upper case B)

### `preserveAspectRatio` should be set to `meet` instead of `slice`

Your `preserveAspectRatio` tells the code to clip nused parts away from the image, instead of trying to fit it to the bottom of the page (I have to say, the MDN article about this is really confusing with their examples)

### `preserveAspectRatio` affects the viewBox, instead of the drawn parts of the page

Since your viewBox has a size of 36 by 200 pixels, it will stay exactly in the center of your svg that has the exact same size.

You can fix this by dynamically altering the size of your viewbox, this makes sure the content always stays where you expect it to be.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '#app-template',
  data: {
    svgHeights: {
        linksBar: 10
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!-- development version, includes helpful console warnings -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<!-- Require an script tag for the vue content here for the case sensitivity issue of the svg viewBox attribute -->
<script type="test/plain" id="app-template">
    <div class="linkClicksBar" >
        <input type=number v-model="svgHeights.linksBar">
        <svg
            width="36px"
            height="200px"
            :viewBox="`0 0 36 ${svgHeights.linksBar * 2}`"
            preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax meet"
        >
            <rect v-bind:height="svgHeights.linksBar * 2 + 'px'" width="36px"></rect>
        </svg>
    </div>
</script>

<div id="app">
</div>
```

### Making it less complicated

While this all looks complicated, there is an even easier solution to your problem, and that using <s>ab</s>using the fact that svg clips automatically at the bottom. Using this we can make a 100% high rect, and change its `y` property depending where we need it

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '#app-template',
  data: {
    svgHeights: {
        linksBar: 10
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!-- development version, includes helpful console warnings -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<!-- Require an script tag for the vue content here for the case sensitivity issue of the svg viewBox attribute -->
<script type="test/plain" id="app-template">
    <div class="linkClicksBar" >
        <input type=number v-model="svgHeights.linksBar">
        <svg
            width="36px"
            height="200px"
            viewBox="0 0 100 100"
            preserveAspectRatio="none"
        >
            <rect :y="100 - svgHeights.linksBar" height="100" width="100"></rect>
        </svg>
    </div>
</script>

<div id="app">
</div>
```

Comment: I usually camelCase, but I somehow got in my head that ViewBox was one word. I always tend to over-complicate whatever I'm working on, so thanks for the help. Now to move on to making Pie charts.